I was using Heob for memory leak detection and found a lot of memory leaks, but a lot of them didn't make sense
I am currently in the final stages of integrating Python with C++. I am trying to use vld and Heob for memory detection, but to my confusion Heob is finding a lot of memory leaks, which in my opinion are very unreasonable. I tried creating a new Qt project and running Heob. It still found leaks.

This is my Heob configuration

This image I did not select external error

I chose external error for this image
I wanted to know if Heob was trustworthy and what the external errors were.

Have you tried Leak details: Detect Leak Types? This should ignore all memory blocks that still have a reference from static/global variables (but also takes longer on program exit).

I have given up using heob and am now using vld. Thank you very much for your reply
